# Расширение функциональности библиотечных классов

Tags: ооп, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

При использовании библиотек не рекомендуется изменять их исходники- это влечёт за собой сложность обновления билиотеки до новой версии а также возможность разрушения её функциональности, особенно если она не покрыта unit-тестами. Однако очень часто требуется расширить функциональность библиотечных классов какими-либо своими часто используемыми методами. Неужели в языках без утиной типизации создание статических классов-сборников функций, принимаюших объект нужного типа как первый аргумент это единственный вариант? Это решение не очень красиво. Например, получившийся код (в Java-подобном синтаксисе) может выглядеть так:

```
import com.thirtpartylibrary.geometry.Vector;
.....
Vector vec1 = new Vector(5,2);
Vector vec2 = new Vector(7,1);
Vector vec3 = MyVectorUtils.Summ(vec1, vec2);
```

а было бы здорово записать последнюю строчку как

```
Vector vec3 = vec1.Add(vec2);
```

или даже

```
Vector vec3 = vec1 + vec2;
```

если язык поддерживает перегрузку операторов, да невозможность изменения библиотечного класса не позволяет.
А какие паттерны проектирования или приёмы используете вы? Мой основной язык разработки - ActionScript 3, хотелось бы узнать такие приёмы и для него.

Comment: в javascript чуть ли не постоянно использую(и не я один) примеси

Comment: ваша проблема решается статик импортом. импортируете все функции написаные вами для работы с векторами и все работает и без дополнительных ухищрений

Comment: Сначала мне казалось, что это то, что нужно, но в итоге это тоже не то- всего лишь сокращение имени, а не расширение класса. К тому же если работа с этими функциями ведётся в нескольких модулях, нужно сделать static import каждой такой функции в каждом модуле, а это не вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В .net для этого используются Extension-методы. Технология работы с данными LINQ построена в основном на них.

Comment: спасибо, очень интересно. вот ссылка на документацию, если кто-то будет искать: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb383977

Answer (score 3):

В контексте Java помогут наследование и композиция. Напишите свою библиотеку, которая "обернет" существующую.

Comment: Действительно, например шаблон "заместитель" как раз подойдет для классов, которые бы хотелось расширить, но от которых нельзя наследоваться.

Comment: Proxy, как паттерн, несколько ограничен, т.к. не изменяет интерфейс проксируемого объекта.

Comment: Строить параллельное дерево классов? Это как раз решение в лоб, которое нежелательно. А при использовании прокси и агрегирования придётся дублировать описание всех методов оборачиваемого класса во внешнем.

Comment: Не всегда наши желания совпадают с нашими возможностями :) В Java других варинтов нет.

Answer (score 2):

А ещё в `ActionScript` 3 есть такая штука "flash.utils.Proxy". Она странная, но иногда позволяет изменить функциональность, которую сложно изменить другими методами. Вот документация, может кому-то и пригодится: [Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

По поводу actionscript могу порекомендовать [пост](http://mixailflash.blogspot.ru/2012/11/array-actionscript.html) в котором приводится пример как можно написать свой аналог Array. Думаю будет познавательная. Я сам в свое время долго тыкался пока не сел и не разобрался что да как.